# Radicals, reaction intermediate, activated complex

Tags: reaction-mechanism, radicals

I'm really confused about those three concepts: radicals, reaction intermediate, activated complex.

1. First of all, in my course we have seen radicals in the context of chain radical reactions. But does it have a wider meaning ? (in older exams of my course I am seeing the word "radical" for reactions that are simple elementary reactions, no propagation and stuff).
2. I have seen the use of an asterisk in the notation of radicals in radical chain reactions. Is it a specific notation for the particular case of radicals inside chain reactions? Not only ?
3. Is it true that all radicals are reaction intermediate but not all reaction intermediate are radicals? The contrary ? None of the 2, how could we describe it then ?
4. About activated complex now, is there any way to distinguish an activated complex (which I understand represent a maximum of energy) from a "classical" reaction intermediate (which I understand represent a local minimum of energy) just by the look at the shape of the chemical reaction(s) ? (so without calculations using specific data about the components).
5. Can we calculate a pseudo-equilibrium constant  (which is related to the fact that we have a steady state, correct me if I'm wrong) either in the case of complex activated and reaction intermediate ?

Thank you very much in advance !

EDIT: I understand your feeling that led you to close this topic. Tbh though, many students of our course were confused about those particular interactions and the point of the post was precisely to shed light on the links (or non links) between all those topics. I understand it may not be very meaningful to others who have had a different (and maybe clearer) learning structure (However, I suppose it would be possible that similar confusions could be happening elsewhere, not just with us).
Also, I think it's worth mentioning that Poutnik's answers were *very* helpful and helped many of my classmates to whom I passed on the information. I respect your choice to close this post but at least you know how it happened behind the scenes.

Comment: Always try to find answers on your own in offline and online resources before asking. The active searching will give you more than just passive waiting to receive an answer.  Write also notes about your prior effort results in the question when asking. As questions that look like it has not been done are frown upon on StackExchange site network and are often closed.  Respondents prefer not to tell you what you already know or what you can easily find. Also, it prevents cumulation of redundant Q/A on this site or internet.

Comment: I did search for it (for a while actually) but I can't find precise information where the distinction (or relation) between those concepts are clearly made. I can only find separate information about those things (but then I don't understand how and how much they are / aren't correlated to each other, hence my confusion).

Comment: Search for what each of it is, then you can make the distinction yourself. Vaque and implicit effort cannot be distinguished from no or negligible effort.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[Radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_(chemistry))** is an atom or a molecule or a ion with an unpaired electron (Some of orbitals contains just a single electron so the electron spins are not paired).

$\ce{Cl^.}$ or $\ce{CH3^.}$ or $\ce{^.O2^.}$ are radicals. Oxygen molecule has 2 unpaired electrons.

Radicals are often also intermediate products in radical reactions.

---

In $\ce{H2 <=> 2 H^.}$, hydrogen atoms as radicals are not intermediate products, as they do not react to something else then $\ce{H2}$.

$\ce{[Al(H2O)5(OH)]^2+(aq)}$ is an intermediate product in $\ce{[Al(H2O)6)]^3+(aq)}$ hydrolysis, but it is not a radical.

---

**[Reaction intermediate/intermediate product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reaction_intermediate)** is a product and at the same time a reagent in the context of a chain of reactions(including, but not limited to, chain reactions), which can be isolated, detected by analytical techniques or just assumed.

Being a radical is more about what an entity is.
Being an intermediate product is more about what an entity does.
so there is a large overlap.

---

**[Excited state](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Excited_state)** is energetic state with higher than the base energy, e.g. with electrons excited in higher orbitals.

A molecule in excited state can be sometimes detected and undergoes further reaction. It is then also an intermediate product.

$$\ce{A ->[h \nu]A^{*}}$$

---

**[Activated complex](https://goldbook.iupac.org/terms/view/A00092)** is a transition state of atoms/molecules/ions happening during formation of products in context of an elementary reaction.

E.g. a reaction $\ce{A + B -> C}$  going like $\ce{A + B -> \ce{AB^{‡}} -> C}$

---

Activated complex has the maximum of potential energy of the reaction, it is kind of standing on the top of a energetic barrier. Intermediate products are existing  entities at the local minimum of energy.

---

In a children game with marble balls and holes, imagine (initial) reactants, (final) products and intermediate reactants/products like balls sitting in some of several adjacent holes. Some holes are deep, some shallow.

OTOH, the activated complexes are the balls in transition between two holes, that cannot stop there. They have to go forward or backward.

Comment: Thank you ! A few remaining points: 1. In my course, all intermediates that are radicals are denoted with * , should I understand that it is only because they are also excited state in that context of being an intermediate, but not because they are radicals? 2. I understand from your explanation that not all reaction intermediates are radicals and also not all radicals are reaction intermediates, sometimes they can be both, or just one, or just the other, right? (I'm asking because our teacher said one of the two, which confused all students).

Comment: Asterisks in superscript position are not used for radicals but excited states. For radicals, there are used "fat dots" in the middle position. ( MathJax cannot do so better AFAIK).

Comment: I see. Lastly, about the hypotheses we can use in different cases, in the case of activated complex: we can calculate a pseudo-equilibrium constant / In the case of reaction intermediate: we can equal their rate of appearance to their rate of disappearance. Correct? Those hypothesis are 2 different things, also correct?

Comment: IP are normal molecules/ions, that can have wide range of concentration, stability and reactivity.  AC are not  true molecules, rather transient state of close interaction of 2 or more entities, before one atomic arrangement transforms to another.

Comment: Thank you for the very nice edits. I said my previous question was the last one so I'm sorry to have another : is a reaction with a reaction intermediate automatically called a chain reaction? (even without propagation ?)

Comment: I have used the term incorrectly. I have meant a chain of reactions, not necessarily (but not excluding) chain reactions. For A -> B -> C,  B is a IP, reactions are chained, but they are not "chain reactions".

Comment: @Poutnik Still too soft after Christmas? ;)

Comment: @Mithoron Rather time by time. :)

Comment: @c.leblanc I have fexed few minor errors, check the current wording. Mainly ***Activated complex** (was: Excited state) has the maximum of potential energy of the reaction, it is kind of standing on the top of a energetic barrier. Intermediate products are existing entities at the local minimum of energy.*